# all path between two nodes in neo4j with TraversalDescription returns incorrect paths

Tags: java, neo4j

I want to find all paths between two nodes. I used these code:

```
TraversalDescription desc = Traversal.description();
            desc.uniqueness(Uniqueness.RELATIONSHIP_GLOBAL);
            desc.evaluator(Evaluators.returnWhereEndNodeIs(graphDb.getNodeById(12)));
            desc.evaluator(Evaluators.includingDepths(3, 3));
            desc.relationships(RelTypes.husband_of).relationships(RelTypes.wife_of).relationships(RelTypes.brother_of).relationships(RelTypes.elti_of) ;
            Traverser traverse = desc.traverse(graphDb.getNodeById(4), graphDb.getNodeById(12));
```

But it does not return the correct paths. It returns paths that has more than 3 depth. Also paths don't end by a node with id 12.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's (primarily) because TraversalDescription uses a fluent API, always returning the modified description. Calling a method on it and ignoring the result has no effect. So you should write

```
TraversalDescription desc = Traversal.description()
        .uniqueness(Uniqueness.RELATIONSHIP_GLOBAL)
        .evaluator(Evaluators.returnWhereEndNodeIs(graphDb.getNodeById(12)))
        .evaluator(Evaluators.includingDepths(3, 3))
        .relationships(RelTypes.husband_of)
        .relationships(RelTypes.wife_of)
        .relationships(RelTypes.brother_of)
        .relationships(RelTypes.elti_of);

Traverser traverse = desc.traverse(graphDb.getNodeById(4), graphDb.getNodeById(12));
```

That said, I'd have a look at the PathFinder API.